# frequency Response/ Bode plot in s=jw

Tags: transfer-function, control-theory

I have a transfer function in s , which has some complex zeros and and poles. I tried to get the bode plot with transfer function in s domain, but did not get the correct result . Moreover how can I get the bode of TF in s=jw ? so that I can get the frequency response on a desired frequency range.

```
 5.639e30 s^6 + 1.375e36 s^4 + 3.78e40 s^2 + 3.315e43
 ----------------------------------------------------
                        3.139e75
```

thanks

Comment: What is the 3.139e75 you are providing?

Comment: its denominator of transfer function